# Clash between revtex4-1 and acronym package

Tags: acronyms, revtex

There seems to be a pretty serious clash between the `revtex4-1` documentclass and the `acronym` package.  The following MWE illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{ABC}{ay bee cee}
\end{acronym}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\ac{ABC}
\end{document}
```

I can also add whatever title, abstract, etc., I want without changing the result.  The real problem appears to be `\maketitle`.  When it is present, the output looks like this:

[image: With <code>\maketitle</code>]

Note the boldface, the random "!", and the fact that the long form of the acronym is not used.  If I comment out `\maketitle`, I get what I expect:

[image: Without <code>\maketitle</code>]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`revtex4-1` is sometimes rather strange. For example, you should define `\author` and `\title` & Co. *after* `\begin{document}`. In this case it seems that the `acronym` environment should also come in the main document. The following code compiles fine for me. [Don't ask why :-)]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{ABC}{ay bee cee}
\end{acronym}
\author{Me}
\title{Title}

\maketitle

Hello world!

\ac{ABC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I removed the author and title just for the sake of minimizing the working example; they didn't make any difference the way I was doing it, though they do now.  More importantly, moving the `acronym` environment into the document itself does make all the difference.  Thanks!

Comment: I had them in the MWE because I was testing `revtex4-1` vs `article`, and the latter protests if you give `\maketitle` without `\author` &Co. But I always forget to put them into the document for `revtex`, and that's what brought me to the idea :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't help if you don't want the list, so use `\acrodef{}`